# Is std::queue having event mechanism( Signals in std::queue)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue, message-queue

Is there any event mechanism or predefined signals in the queue. If any data or message comes in the queue the queue should generate an event saying data is ready to process. Or signal other thread to do his task Instead of continuously polling to the queue.

In posix Message Queue there is function like `mq_notify()` which will notify to other process or thread if any data comes in the Message queue so we can avoid Polling.

**Edit**

If not, So how can I achieve this on `std::queue`. I want to avoid polling continuously it is slowing down the performance of the code.

Whenever some event occur on the queue it should notify to others.

Comment: std::deque is not designed to be used directly with threads. you have to do synchronization yourself, including signaling.

Comment: @DonReba Is TBB's Queues supported by AMD processor.

Comment: @ali786, TBB (thread-building blocks) is cross-platform.

Comment: @DonReba thanks i thought that they are architecture dependent and can be executed only on intel threaded cpu's.

Comment: It works for a wide range of processors, including AMD's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.  The simplest is to have an asynchronous queue, implemented using a mutex and condition variable, on which a thread blocks, waiting for another thread to push something onto the queue.  This is a very common idiom for task dispatching and here are two simple implementations:

http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html and
http://cxx-gtk-utils.sourceforge.net/2.2/classCgu_1_1AsyncQueueDispatch.html

By using a list rather than a deque as the queue container you can allocate new nodes outside the queue's mutex which significantly improves performance under high contention (see the source code for the second link mentioned above for an example using std::list::splice to achieve this).

Instead of having a designated thread block on the asynchronous queue, after a thread places an item on the queue it could instead invoke an event in the program's event loop which executes a callback which extracts the item from the queue and does something with it.  Implementing this is more OS-specific but see http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.NotificationQueue.html and http://cxx-gtk-utils.sourceforge.net/2.2/classCgu_1_1Notifier.html for different approaches to this.

Answer (score 3):

std::queue is a containter type, not an event mechanism. I recommend making a class around the queue that implements a message queue.

EDIT:
Ok, so

So I recommend using an std::queue, std::mutex, and a std::condition_variable, if you use boost that has the same types. Putting those in your new Queue class and when pushing, you would lock the mutex, push onto the queue, unlock the mutex, and notify_one() the condition. That way the condition variable is notified only when pushed. You can do the same on pop.

Comment: which message queue posix or BSD, Posix Message queue has an event mechanism.

Comment: Will you elaborate what should I do.